# how to define in TestCafe a classname selector showing multiple times?

Tags: css, testing, xpath, automated-tests, testcafe

Im struggling to define a Selector in TestCafe that clicks that **YES button in the photo below**
[image]

I can find and click the fist YEs button like

```html
  .click(Selector('.c-segmented-control__label').withExactText("Yes"))
```

However the second Yes button has the same classname so my Script cannot find it, how can I define the Selector for that one? I have tried child, nth and all but it doesnt find it.

Thanks

Comment: `Selector('.c-segmented-control__label').nth(1)` doesn't work? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to below code

```
const yesButton  = Selector('.c-segemented-control__label');
        const count = await yesButton.count;
        for(let i=0;i<count;i++){
            let text = await yesButton.parent().parent().textContent //REACH UNTIL YOU GET PARENT 
            if(text.includes("YOURTEXT")){
                await yesButton.nth(i).click()
            }
        }
```

OR You can take top to bottom approach, match you text and find child node by using .child or find